# How to convert NumberDecimal to Double in MongoDB shell?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, decimal, bigdecimal, mongo-shell

I have a document with "test" filed as `NumberDecimal` type

```
{ "_id" : ObjectId("5d1a202e476381c30cd995a4"),  "test" : NumberDecimal("0.1") }
```

How to convert "test" field from `NumberDecimal` to `Double` in mongodb shell?

I tried execute

```
db.collection.find({"test": {$exists: true}}).forEach(function (x) {   x.test = parseFloat(x.test);   db.collection.save(x); });
```

but don't solve this problem because it return NaN

Answer (score 11, accepted):

The decimal type is not native to JavaScript, so NumberDecimal values in the shell are special wrappers representing the BSON value stored in MongoDB. If you want to use `parseFloat()` you can convert a NumberDecimal to JSON in order to access the string value. For example, in your original code this would be: `parseFloat(x.test.toJSON()["$numberDecimal"])` .

However, a better approach would be to use the aggregation framework to manipulate decimal values including arithmetic operations (MongoDB 3.4+) and type conversion (MongoDB 4.0+).

MongoDB 4.0+ includes a [`$toDouble()` expression](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/toDouble/) that will convert numeric values (decimal, int, long, boolean, date, string) to a double. The aggregation framework in MongoDB 4.0 cannot be used to update documents (unless you want to create a new collection or replace the existing collection using [`$out`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/out/)), so you would have to run an aggregation query to convert the values and then separately apply document updates:

```js
// Find matching documents
var docs = db.collection.aggregate([
    { $match: {
        test: { $exists: true }
    }},

    // Add a new field converting the decimal to a double
    // (alternatively, the original "test" value could also be replaced)
    { $addFields: {
        testDouble: { $toDouble: "$test" }
    }}
])

// Update with the changes (Note: this could be a bulk update for efficiency)
docs.forEach(function (doc) {
     db.collection.update({ _id: doc._id}, {$set: { testDouble: doc.testDouble }});
});

// Check the results
> db.collection.find().limit(1)
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5d1a202e476381c30cd995a4"),
    "test" : NumberDecimal("0.1"),
    "testDouble" : 0.1
}
```

MongoDB 4.2 (currently in RC) adds support for using some [aggregation stages for updates](https://docs.mongodb.com/master/reference/method/db.collection.update/#update-with-an-aggregation-pipeline), so in 4.2 the above update can be more concisely expressed as:

```
db.collection.updateMany(
    { test: { $exists: true }},
    [ { $addFields: { testDouble: { $toDouble: "$test" }}}]
)
```

Comment: @Stenie: Thank you for your answer!
I also solve this problem with string processing like 

`db.collection.find({"test": {$exists: true}}).forEach(function (x) {   var s = x.test.toString().split('"')[1]; x.test = parseFloat(s);   db.collection.save(x); });`

But I think your solution is the best ^^