# MongoDB query to get objects inside Coordinates

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

Im trying to build an endpoint that will return every vechicle that i have inside some coordinates width. I have been looking into $near and maxdistance but so far no results.

```
et RentalSchema = new Schema({
  start: [
    {
      date: {
        type: Date
      }
    },
    {
      location: [
        {
          index: {
            type: String
          },
          type: {
            type: String,
            enum: ['Point'],
            required: true
          },
          coordinates: {
            type: [Number],
            required: true
          }
        }
      ],
      range: { type: Number }
    }
  ],
  end: [
    {
      date: {
        type: Date
      }
    },
    {
      location: [
        {
          index: {
            type: String
          },
          type: {
            type: String,
            enum: ['Point'],
            required: true
          },
          coordinates: {
            type: [Number],
            required: true
          }
        }
      ],
      range: { type: Number }
    }
  ],
  /*status: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['confirmed ', 'canceled '],
    default: ['confirmed ']
  },*/
  price: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  rentalMethod: {
    type: String,
    enum: ['minutes', 'pack'],
    default: 'minutes'
  },
  code: {
    type: Number,
    required: true
  },
  vehicle: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Vehicle'
  }
});

module.exports = mongoose.model('Rentals', RentalSchema, 'Rentals');
```

This is my rental schema

```
'use strict';
const mongoose = require('mongoose');

let Schema = mongoose.Schema;
/**
 * @typedef VehicleSchema
 * @property {string} code.required
 */
let VehicleSchema = new Schema({
  code: {
    type: Number,
    required: [true, 'code of vehicle']
  },
  description: {
    type: String
  },
  place: {
    type: mongoose.Schema.Types.ObjectId,
    ref: 'Places'
  }
});
module.exports = mongoose.model('Vehicles', VehicleSchema, 'Vehicles');
```

This is my vechile schema.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/P7UK9.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/FqSTT.png

https://i.stack.imgur.com/CAD46.png

Could anyone help me with this query please since i have no idea about how to build it ?
The idea would be to have an endpoint like this
`{{HOST}}:{{PORT}}/vehicles/:lat/:lon?range=200`

Where you would put the coordinates and the range and it would return all the vehicles that are within those coordinates. Any help ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to [geospatial-queries](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/geospatial-queries/). you can run query like this. But you have to make sure you create a `Index` first using

```
db.places.createIndex( { location: "2dsphere" } )
```

As You are receiving `lat` and `long` from `params` and `range` form `query` you can just input it in your query like this. I'm assuming range means `0-200` so `min is 0` and `max is 200`

```
db.places.find(
       {
         location:
           { $near:
              {
                $geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: [ req.params.lat, req.params.lon ] },
                $minDistance: 0,
                $maxDistance: req.query.range
              }
           }
       }
    )
```

And I'm not sure what `Index's` use for in `location array` in your schema, but if not needed you can remove it.

**Update**

You can use `parseFloat` to convert the incoming request objects to points

```
$geometry: { type: "Point",  coordinates: [ parseFloat(req.params.lat), parseFloat(req.params.lon) ] },
```

Comment: Im having this error
"errmsg" : "Can't extract geo keys: { _id: ObjectId('5df8b38f79ca3b3ecd23bf41'), location: [ { type: \"Point\", coordinates: [ 41.530735, -8.621205 ], index: \"2dsphere\" } ], range: 200, capacity: 200, quantity: 100 }  Point must only contain numeric elements",

Comment: Check the update and also can you explain the usage of `index` field in `location array`, because i have a feeling that might interfere but not sure?

Comment: The index was to create the 2dsphere. But i was doing it wrong. can i use the parseFloat to query on the mongo shell ?

Comment: If you are using mongo shell look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/56895903/7482427) and also i don't think you need to add `index` field because you don't add a field if you wish to create an index you just run `createIndex()` in order to do so.